# Show that $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

> **Problem.**
>
> Let $\emptyset \subset A\subset X$ and $\emptyset \subset B\subset Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are connected, show that $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$ is also connected by **using the criteria of connectedness that if for any continuous function $f$ such that $f:X\to \{\pm1\}$, $f$ is constant then $X$ is connected**.

I began by assuming that there exists a function $f:(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)\to\{\pm1\}$ which is continuous but not constant but couldn't proceed any further beyond that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$ is connected](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214317/prove-that-x-times-y-setminus-a-times-b-is-connected)

Comment: @Magdiragdag: The question is not a duplicate of the question you linked. The linked question has no restriction on using a particular criteria to prove the claim, whereas this question has.

Comment: In that case, please add that to the question. Can you explain where you are having trouble translating that proof to your setting? (Note that your notion of connectedness is the usual one, just formulated in a particular way).

Comment: @Magdiragdag: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/214411/170039) I understand that if $x_0\not \in A$ and if $\varphi:\{x_0\}\times Y\to \{\pm 1\}$ be a continuous function then $\varphi$ is constant because if $i:X\times Y\to \{x_0\}\times Y$ defined by $i(x,y)=(x_0,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ is continuous and then since the composition of two continuous function is continuous and (in this case) $X\times Y$ is connected $\varphi\circ i:X\times Y\to\{\pm 1\}$ is a constant function, so $(\varphi\circ i)(x,y)$ is constant.

Comment: Consequently it follows that $φ$ is also constant and we are done. But I don't understand how the part of the first bullet starting from "and..." follows and how can I translate it to my setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is essentially the same as the one linked to. Suppose we have a function $f:(X\times Y)\setminus(A\times B)\to\{\pm1\}$. Begin by choosing $a\in X\setminus A$ and $b\in Y\setminus B$ (which is possible because both are proper subsets). Now, let $(x,y)\in(X\times Y)\setminus(A\times B)$ be arbitrary. We will show that $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$.

Because $(x,y)\notin A\times B$, either $x\notin A$ or $y\notin B$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x\notin A$. Then $\{x\}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ and contained in $(X\times Y)\setminus(A\times B)$, so the restriction $f|_{\{x\}\times Y}$ is constant. Similarly, $X\times\{b\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$ and contained in $(X\times Y)\setminus(A\times B)$, so $f|_{X\times\{b\}}$ is constant. Hence

$$f(x,y)=f(x,b)=f(a,b)$$

and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:X\times Y\rightarrow (X\times Y)/(A\times B)$ be the quotient map; it is surjective. Consider a continuous function $f:(X\times Y)/ (A\times B)\to\{\pm1\}$. $f\circ p$ is continuous; since $X\times Y$ is connected, $f\circ p$ is constant. Since $p$ is surjective, $f$ is constant.

Comment: I don't anything about quotient map. Can it be done without using the idea of quotient map?

Comment: @TsemoAristide How are $f$ and $p$ composed? $p$ has as codomain $(X \times Y) / (A \times B)$, but $f$ has as domain $(X \times Y) \setminus (A \times B)$.