# Show that $(X\times Y)\smallsetminus(A\times B)$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Problem** Let $A$ be a proper subset of $X$ , and let $B$ be a proper subset of $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are connected, Show that $(X\times Y)\smallsetminus(A\times B)$ is connected.

I wanna prove it by contradiction. I know the alternative proof which is
[here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214317/469000)

Thanks!

Comment: Proof by contradiction is super easy to shoehorn into any argument: "Suppose the result is untrue. Then, by *insert proof here* the result is true, contradicting our supposition. Therefore the result is true." Did you perhaps want an argument that more directly shows that two disjoint open sets cannot cover the given set?

Comment: @user804886 If $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)=C\cup D$ forms a separation. 
What next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Z:=(X\times Y)\setminus(A\times B)$ is disconnected by disjoint open subsets $U,V\subseteq Z$.

For $x\notin A$, $y\notin B$, let $C_{x,y}:=(\{x\}\times Y)\cup(X\times\{y\})$, the connected cross formed from the pair $(x,y)$.

Suppose $(x,y)\in U$. Then, $x\notin A$ or $y\notin B$. For the former, since $\{x\}\times Y$ is connected, it must be entirely in $U$, so there is a pair $(x,y')\in U$, $y'\notin B$. For the latter, $X\times\{y\}$ is connected, so similarly we can assume there is $x'\notin A$. In any case there is a pair $(x',y')\in U$, $x'\notin A$, $y'\notin B$. But $C_{x',y'}$ is connected, so it must be entirely in $U$.

Any pair $(x,y)$ with either $x\notin A$ **or** $y\notin B$ must belong to $U$. For the former, the connected set $\{x\}\times Y$ intersects $C_{x',y'}$ in $(x,y')$, so their union is connected and thus belongs to $U$. Similarly for the latter case. Thus any such $(x,y)\in U$, so $U\supseteq Z$, leaving $V=\emptyset$.